# Minimal set to represent any positive integer under some limit as a sum of at most two elements

Tags: number-theory

I am trying to figure out an algorithm that, given $n \ge 1$, produces a set $\{x_i\}$ of minimal size, such that any $1 \le m \le n$ can be represented either as $m = x_i$ or $m = x_i + x_j$ (possibly with $i = j$).

I know that if I raise the limit to at most three elements, the set of prime numbers below $n$ (with the addition of $1$) works because of Goldbach conjecture, and it seems to be the minimal one (but I can't prove it). But what is the minimum set size for the sum of at most two elements? Perhaps it is a known problem?